# Convert List to map using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am working on sorting a map by values code using java 8.

I have done most of the thing but I am not getting how to convert the list to map using java 8 features

```
public class SortMapByValue {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", 3);
    map.put("V", 1);
    map.put("Anss", 9);
    map.put("D", 5);
    map.put("E", 2);
    map.put("F", 10);

    HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());


    Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1.getValue() - o2.getValue());

    // Need to this using Java 8 -- start

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    } 

    // Need to this using Java 8 -- end

    newMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v));

    }
}
```

Comment: *I am working on sorting a map by values* => `Entry::comparingByValue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sort `Map` based on values use `Entry.comparingByValue()` and then collect them to `LinkedHashMap` :

```
Map<String,Integer> result =   map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a,b) -> b, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

In [Java-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) there are three overloaded `toMap` method, the above one is with 4 Parameters which is

```
public static <T,K,U,M extends Map<K,U>> Collector<T,?,M> toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                                                            Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
                                                            BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                                                            Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

**Parameters:**

> keyMapper - a mapping function to produce keys
>
> valueMapper - a mapping function to produce values
>
> mergeFunction - a merge function, used to resolve collisions between 
>   values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)
>
> mapSupplier - a function which returns a new, empty Map into which the results will be inserted

Comment: I understood everything except `(a,b)->a, LinkedHashMap::new)`. what is happening here ? I mean I can see you creating a new instance if LinkedHashMap but what is `(a,b) -> a` doing ?

Comment: The third argument is the `merge` function. It takes two maps and merges them into one map. I think in this example it is assumed that there will be no duplicate keys and so no two maps actually have to be merged, therefore the merge function can simply return the first map since it will never actually be called. You could presumably put a null there but I haven't tested it. [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Comment: Third function is uniqueKeyMapper. if there are duplicate keys in your list, then you choose which one to proceed with

Comment: Shouldn't the merge function be `(a, b) -> b` in this case?

Comment: updated and i agree but since we are processing the `Map` data i don't think there is any use of merge function @YassinHajaj

Comment: @Deadpool Indeed in the example we only have unique keys, but following the algorithm 100% is cleaner I think. Nice answer btw

Comment: `(a,b)->a` , will ensure that if there is any duplicate key then take the first.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map map = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
        entry -> entry.getKey(), // keyMapper
        entry -> entry.getValue(), // valueMapper
        (first, second) -> first,  // mergeFunction
        () -> new LinkedHashMap<>() // mapFactory
    )
);
```

See [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier))

you can even do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", 3);
        map.put("V", 1);
        map.put("Anss", 9);
        map.put("D", 5);
        map.put("E", 2);
        map.put("F", 10);

        Map newMap = map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    entry -> entry.getKey(), // keyMapper
                    entry -> entry.getValue(), // valueMapper
                    (first, second) -> first,  // mergeFunction
                    () -> new LinkedHashMap<>() // mapFactory
                )
            );

        newMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v));

    }
```